# Recycling variable names for mysqli results?

Tags: php, mysqli, theory

Is there a benefit or drawback to using the same variable to store the results of consequetive mysql queries, like this example?

```
$res = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE Research SET Progress=Progress+1 WHERE ID=1");
$res = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT Progress FROM Research WHERE ID=1");
$res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
```

Comment: If you don't want to receive something from your first query, then there should be no problem. You will just overwrite the variable by assigning it.

Comment: why assign the output to a variable at all if your not going to use it? just call `mysqli_query( ...` your don't need the `$res=` in front at all

Comment: @Dagon I feel illuminated. Thank you for the tip! And thank you everyone, I think the subject has been sufficienty answered!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do it all the time.  I copy and past those lines routinely.  the only drawback is if you need an additional query while looping through the results of the first, in which case, things will get ugly. In those cases, you will need a unique name for the second query.